# custom python IDEA debugger type renderer that requires an import

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to add a [custom type renderer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-views.html#renderers) in the IDEA Python debugger.
Specifically, I would like to render an [xml Element](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) from the standard xml package as a string, e.g. `<x a=1><y>2</y></x>`

The code to do so is `ElementTree.tostring(self)` where `self` represents the variable or watch in the debugger.

ElementTree needs to be imported so I have unsuccessful tried:

```py
xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(self)
```

and

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
ElementTree.tostring(self)
```

In both cases I got an error `Unable to evaluate: name 'xml' is not defined` in the debugger watch window. See screenshot:

[image: custom renderer error]

The docs don't mention such cases where importing of the rendering function is required.

Has anyone been able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I managed to get it working with a dynamic import:

```py
__import__('xml').etree.ElementTree.tostring(self)
```